# How to determine whether Vue component is destroyed due to hot reload?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, hot-module-replacement

I have a Vue component that manages heavy resources that are expensive to set up (namely, WebRTC `PeerConnection` with video streams). The component is designed in a way so these heavy resources are saved elsewhere and are preserved across module reloads. When component is reloaded (destroyed & created again) it checks for saved stream and just redeploys it without recreation.

This, however, implies that `destroyed` hook actualy does not destroy anything. Which is not expected behavior when user leaves the page and component is destroyed completely, not for reloading.

So the question is: how to tell whether the component is destroyed to be reloaded (and resources should be left intact) or because it is no longer needed (and resources should be closed)?

I use Nuxt, so webpack configuration and other low-level related things are managed by Nuxt itself. No changes to Nuxt config were made in this area.

Comment: I guess destroyed should be default and some env should preserve states? So better tell to keep instead to guess not to keep

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a way to distinguish between the two events (there isn't a "hot reload" flag of some kind in the component's lifecycle hooks). I would just use a debouncer during development mode: delay the closing of the stream (e.g., for 200ms) in `destroyed` with `setTimeout`, and stop that timer in `created`, which should happen shortly for hot-reload.

Comment: do you need close camera on destroy?

Comment: Not the camera (it is recv-only stream), but yes, stream should be closed upon destorying.

Answer (score 0):

In complete honesty, I still don't have quite clear your issue.

Although it could come in handy for you knowing about this.

```html
    if (module.hot) {
      module.hot.addStatusHandler(status => {
        if (status === 'idle') {
             // do code here
        }
      })
    }
```